# Python request not using proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I wrote a simple python script to make a request to this website http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test using the `requests` module.

This website essentially tells you whether the request is using a proxy or not. According to the website, the request is not going through a proxy and is in fact going through my IP address.

Here is the code:

```
proxiesLocal = {
   'https': proxy
}
headers = RandomHeaders.LoadHeader()
url = "http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test"
res = ''
while (res == ''):
    try:
        res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxiesLocal)
        proxyTest = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
        items = proxyTest.find_all("p")
        print(len(items))
        for item in items:
            print(item.text)
        quit()
    except:
        print('sleeping')
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
```

Assuming that proxy is a variable of `type string` that stores the address of the proxy, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check whether `proxy` is in the valid IP format.

Comment: Here’s the format of the proxy I’m passing in: ip:port:username:password